# How to send Body in to consume Request method using spring reactive webclient?

Tags: java, spring-webclient

I have to consume this endpoint: `localhost:5100/message/v1?topic=test.state.v2`

This endpoint requires a body like this JSON:

```json
{"topic":"test.state.v2"}
```

When I test this endpoint with this cURL returns correctly the response data.

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET --data '{"topic": "test.state.v1"}' http://localhost:5100/test/message/v1`

I'm using this client to consume:

```java
public class MyClient {
//imports.. here

private final String dataStoreHostAndPort = "http://localhost:5100";
private finalJSONObject MY_BODY = new JSONObject().put("topic", "test.state.v1");

    public MyClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
         HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 200)
                .followRedirect(true)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(200));
    
        webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(dataStoreHostAndPort)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
    }
    
    
    public Mono<String> getMessage() {
        return this.webClient
                .method(HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri(builder -> builder
                        .path("/message/v1")
                        .queryParam("topic", "log.state.v1").build())
                .body((BodyInserter<?, ? super ClientHttpRequest>) MY_BODY)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }

}
```

I used practically all forms of `body(BodyInserter)` and the `uri()`  but nothing worked.

How can I send `MY_BODY` to Spring Reactive `WebClient` request in the same way than cURL does?

Comment: Please clarify your question. `localhost:5100/message/v1?topic=test.state.v2` looks like a GET request with query parameters, and you use GET in your code. But you also say that there is a request body.

Comment: Do you receive a meaningful Http response or error, or any useful logs that you can share?
To me it seems like you have almost the same thing in your uri.queryparam and the webclient.body.

Also what is the response you receive from the cURL?
Seems like you are mixing some GET and Curl syntax there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.body(BodyInserters.fromValue(YOUR_VALUE_HERE))`

Comment: Thank you for your anwer @red.  One question more, how can I get that body inserted in the consumed service?.